# Jquery change() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi everyone I am new to jquery. I am facing a problem with change function I jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

  $("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text">
<p>Write something in the input field, and then press enter or click outside the field.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting an alert box when I press it outside the textbox. Please help me to resolve this issue :D

Comment: It's always a good idea to view your browser console whenever you're working on Javascript things. You will probably have received an error message of some kind there, which would tell you more about the actual problem.

Comment: @GregHewgill - it's definitely a good idea to check the console for errors, but in this case I don't believe there'll be an error: the code shown is syntactically valid and will execute, it just won't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to add a change handler to an element before it is added to the dom. You can use dom [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback to delay the script execution till all the elements are loaded to the dom

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLbIvmJkPCJ18UTx2cFn?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this :

```
    $(function() {
     $("input").change(function(){
            alert("The text has been changed.");
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").change(function(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside the:

```
$(function(){
    // Your code
});
```

The script will wait the DOM ready to start.